# Firebase cloud function read/update database on https.onrequest()

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

firebase-cloud-function noob here.

I'm struggling in trying to to read a database value from a https firebase cloud function.
For example putting this `https://us-central1-database-daa11.cloudfunctions.net/test?deviceID=DEV-14SfJ6` in the browser should return a web page showing `lmvBlnf9dhXvbc8SuOD3it`

I have following database structure:

```
{
  "devices" : {
    "DEV-14SfJ6" : {
      "mode" : "die_hard",
      "registred" : "true",
      "user" : "lmvBlnf9dhXvbc8SuOD3it"
    },
    "DEV-3Xrcwr" : {
      "mode" : "die_hard",
      "registred" : "true"
      "user" : "lmvBlnf9dhXvbc8SuOD3it"
    }
}
```

and I have deploy the following test function to read the user parameter for a device. For example DEV-14SfJ6.

```js
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');
    const admin = require('firebase-admin');
    admin.initializeApp();
    //
    //
    //

    exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
        var db = admin.database();
        const deviceID = request.query.deviceID;
        console.log("Sent device ID", deviceID);
        response.send("test ok");

        var val2;
        db.ref("/devices/" + deviceID + "/user").once("value").then(snap => {
          val2 = snap.val();
          response.statusCode(200).send(val2);
          console.log(val2)
          return db.ref("/devices/" + deviceID + "/user").set(val1+1);
        }).catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
          response.send("error occurred");
        });
      });
```

but as you would expect nothing good happens.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function has several problems.

First, `val1` is never actually defined.  It's not clear what you're trying to do by setting the `/devices/DEVICEID/user` (a string in the original data) to `val1 + 1`.

Second, `statusCode` isn't a function, you want `status(200)` (or just omit it, 200 is the default).

But the real problem you have is the general handling of the function semantics and promises.

For http/https functions, the [function terminates](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events#terminate_http_functions) once you call `response.send()`.

So, you want to make sure your database update happens before you do that.  Moreover, your function calls `send` twice -- once before it accesses the database, and then once after the first call to the database (and once in the catch).

Fixing will look something like this, but since it isn't clear what you are trying to do, I can't give exact code:

```js
exports.test = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  var db = admin.database();
  const deviceID = request.query.deviceID;
  console.log("Sent device ID", deviceID);

  var val2;
  db.ref("/devices/" + deviceID + "/user").once("value").then(snap => {
    val2 = snap.val();
    console.log(val2)
    return db.ref("/devices/" + deviceID + "/user").set('some new value');
  }).then(() => {
    response.status(200).send(val2);
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
    response.send("error occurred");
  });
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Sorry for not making it more clear what I want to do. Unfortunately your code is not compiling.  `28:14  warning  Avoid nesting promises                      promise/no-nesting
  29:15  error    Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return`

Comment: This is a [lint error](https://github.com/xjamundx/eslint-plugin-promise/blob/master/docs/rules/no-nesting.md) (not a compile error) that can be safely ignored.  But, I think I've updated my code to get around it.

Comment: probably you are right but I was not able to deploy the function like that. In the meantime I also managed to clear the code and now is working. thanks.

Comment: I am using this code to create a link that will be accessed by an IoT device. With an HTTP request by using his name, the device will post 1 on its shadow from Firebase Realtime Database so that the user knows that the device is online. IoT device will trigger this link at around 10s. <br/> A second cron function will be triggered at a period of 1 min setting all existing devices to 0. By doing this I will be able to see when a device is online or offline.